# Building libcurl with static linking to openssl

Tags: openssl, libcurl, static-linking, nm

I am trying to build libcurl with static linking to openssl. So to achieve that, I have used following configuration:

OpenSSL:

```
LDFLAGS="-static”
LIBS="-ldl”
```

cURL:

```
LDFLAGS="-static”
CPPFLAGS="-I$(CURDIR)/$(3RDPARTY_DIR)$(OPENSSL)/include   
LDFLAGS="-L$(CURDIR)/$(3RDPARTY_DIR)$(OPENSSL)"
./configure --disable-shared --without-zlib --without-libidn --without-librtmp --disable-ldap —-with-ssl=<path where my openssl is installed>
```

With this, I am to generate libcurl.a and link it to my code where I am successfully able to handle HTTPS connections, as per my need.

But for the sake of learning purpose, I wanted to know are SSL symbols actually integrated into libcurl or not. 
So for that, I tried using `nm` command:

```
nm -A libcurl.a | grep “SSL_"
```

But it shows all SSL symbols as Undefined. For example,

```
U SSL_connect
U SSL_ctrl
```

So does it mean that symbols from libssl.a and libcrypto.a are NOT actually integrated into libcurl?

If yes, what can be done to actually integrate them into libcurl.a?

Any help is appreciated to help me understand this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it means that the OpenSSL symbols are *not* integrated into libcurl.

When you build a static version of libcurl, you get a `libcurl.a` file suitable for static linking. But you then need to *also* provide all the (static) dependency libraries as well on the linker command line, you don't normally link them all together into a single static lib first. (If you want that done, you will have to do it yourself; the curl build system won't do it.)

When you want to link your application with a static libcurl built to use a static OpenSSL, you link your application and provide all the necessary libs on the linker command line. On a *nix that means `-lcurl -lcrypto -lssl`...

(Most libcurl builds will also use additional dependencies).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried adding openssl dependency in linker command line  but it doesn't seem to work for me. I have updated my openssl and curl linking config above. Where I may be making mistake?

Comment: Show us details. Your link command line and the errors you get!

Comment: Actually, I don't get any errors. But symbols are not shown in nm command output (nm -A libcurl.a | grep "SSL"). That's the reason I suspect. Linking config details are already mentioned in the question above in cURL configuration section.

Comment: libcurl will not provide those symbols, they're provided by the OpenSSL lib. Link your program and `ldd` it to verify that it is static and if that works, you're good. You're looking at the wrong thing.

Comment: Aah.. got it. I linked the program and did ldd (which should list shared libraries). It shows: " linux-vdso.so.1 => (0x00007fff01ffe000) libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007f2fcd118000) libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f2fccefa000) libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f2fccbf3000) libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f2fcc82d000) /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f2fcd351000)"

Comment: As ldd lists dynamic dependencies, it doesn't show libcurl in my ldd output. But my application works fine. So does it mean it is statically linked correctly?

Comment: Exactly. By *not* showing with ldd, but still working in the app, you know that the functionality has been linked statically.